# How to set up menu with links to pages in different languages on multilingual sites?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site determining the language from the URL Path (www.sample.com/lang/page). I need a menu to have a mix of links to pages in both English and French. 99% of these are node pages, one or two are taxonomies. We do not have any translated content only localized. It doesn't seem to make a difference what Translation mode my menu is in (I've tried all three) the system always adds "fr/" in-front of every URL when I put the menu on french pages, even if that node id doesn't exist in french. I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I can't figure out how... Here's a sample of what i am looking for in one menu:

- About Us - www.sample.com/about-us (not translating to french, but want to link to it from french pages)
- Contactez-nous -   www.sample.com/fr/contactez-nous ( node in french, not a translation of another page)
- US Locations- www.sample.com/locations (not translating to french, but want to link to it from french pages)

I'm sure this must be possible, but I have no idea how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

How about using "language neutral", or "Indépendant de langue" in French? That's an option you should have on the node "edit" form ("modifier" in French) for each of those 3 pages. And then combine this with creating a (single) menu link, in the appropriate menu of course.

That should make such link show up for both languages. That's how I always implement such pages, typically for pages similar to the ones you mentioned. Or sometimes in cases where some translation is still missing, and at least such page should be shown already in another language for which its content is available already.

FYI: I'm also using "determine language from the URL path").